# Unexpected error message while extracting vectors from a list

Tags: r, list, function, vector, dimension

I want to extract vectors from a list of text files.

First define the correct "working directory" and then I generate a list that contains a the test files.

```
file.list <- list.files(pattern="*.txt", full.names=T)
```

Afterwards I format the data the right way.

```
datalist = lapply(file.list, FUN=read.table, header = F, sep = "\t", skip = 2)
```

And eventually I define the vectors which should be extracted.

```
cmbn = expand.grid(1:641, 1:977)
flen = length(datalist)
lapply(1:(nrow(cmbn)),function(t,lst,cmbn){
  return(sapply(1:flen,function(i,t1,lst1,cmbn1){
    return(lst1[[i]][cmbn1$Var1[t1],cmbn1$Var2[t1]])},t,lst,cmbn))}
  ,datalist,cmbn)
```

In the end I got as an output all the vectors. But how can I store them in a clever way? I want to be able to access the vectors individually.

Comment: Just a guess. But going by your question `file.list <- list.files(pattern="*.txt", full.names=T)` just contains names of your files and not the data in the files. Please share output of `nrow(file.list[[1]])` and  `ncol(file.list[[1]])`. If your file is comma separated, you can read a file using `read.csv()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "incorrect number of dimensions" indicates that `lst1[[i]]` does not possess two dimensions. When `dim` returns `NULL`, it indicates that `lst1[[i]]` is not even a matrix nor array.

Try using `str(lst1[[i]])` to take a look at the *str*ucture of the element. Is it vector? Is it something else? Or is it simply missing (`NULL`)?

When you know what is wrong, you can fix it. It could be reading an empty file, or that you are reading an index outside of the bounds of the list due to ??

Comment: Something is really wrong with my approach. 
When I check the structure of the lst1 element (str(lst1[[i]]), then I get the response that :object 'lst1' not found

Comment: Is the problem maybe at the step where I generate the list? Are there more information necessary. For example: header = F, sep="\t"

Comment: We cannot say. We know nothing of your files, their names, their data structures, so the problem could be literally anywhere inside your computer. You've furthermore completely changed your question to something else, without providing explanation of what you've or why, or what you are trying to accomplish.